Cognito support for Plus Addressing [VERP]
I'm using cognito with my software and I would like su support VERP.
I want to register in my software as a different user:

claudio@domain.com
claudio+admin@domain.com

I have succesfully created users via admin create user api (self enrollment is disabled in my usecase)
But trying to set a new password I receive this error from cognito api backend:
{
    "code": "InvalidParameterException",
    "name": "InvalidParameterException",
    "message": "2 validation errors detected: Value at 'userAlias' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{S}\\p{N}\\p{P}]+; Value at 'userName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{S}\\p{N}\\p{P}]+"
}

Is there any way to edit these constraints ?
I have not found anywhere in documentation or configuration references to this.
